# Elasticsearch - indexing and searching on postal addresses

Tags: elasticsearch

I am creating an elasticsearch index from a database table using the jdbc-river plugin, which is touching a customer table joined with a customer's address table, a one-to-many relationship

Currently, the database has separate fields for address information into street1, street2, street3, city, state, zip respectively

here is a snippet of the search  i conduct on customers and their addresses, i am conducting a boolean query that should multi-match on the street fields, and match queries on the others, minimum should match of 3

```
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "should": [
            {
               "match": {
                  "FIRST_NAME": {
                     "query": "James"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "match": {
                  "LAST_NAME": "Smith"
               }
            },
        {
           "multi_match": {
              "query": "10020 Pacific Mesa",
              "fields": [
                 "STREET1",
                 "STREET2",
                 "STREET3"
              ]
           }
        },
        {
           "match": {
              "CITY": "San Diego"
           }
        },
        {
           "match": {
              "STATE_CODE": "CA"
           }
        },
        {
               "match": {
                  "ZIPCODE": "92121"
               }
            }
         ],
         "minimum_should_match": "3"
      }
   }
}
```

While this works, it can provide high scores for customers who match the first name, city and zipcode, as they have met the criteria of minimum 3 matches

My question is, how can I improve on this setup?

Ideas/Questions i had were:

1. is it an issue of boosting , say street over state/zip?
2. Should i be ignoring state altogether, since zip should correlate
   to state anyways?
3. Should i just be indexing all of the street fields together as one rather than performing a multi-match on three fields
4. Is match good enough, or should i be looking into creating synonyms , as user input could be "112 Second Ave" versus "112 **2nd** Avenue"

I honestly am just looking for suggestions and guides for making the highest quality search, I attempted looking for examples but found no relevant info regarding postal address indexing

Anyways, thanks for your time

Comment: The question I would have when trying to solve a problem like this is "what am I trying to solve". Are you trying to find exactly one person, are you trying to give a nice amount of results while remaining as accurate as possible? What information is repeatable and therefore worth filtering on instead of matching?

Comment: I am trying to find the closest match to an existing person, so I am assuming nice amount of results as accurate as possible. I was using query instead of filters as my search criteria will be user input and therefore unpredictable

Comment: Are you looking for a person in an area? Or are you looking for an area with people? It would seem like with so many fields you're looking for a particular person? Or are the search parameters very open ended?

Comment: I am looking for a particular person, They have filled out their name and address in an anonymous online form , and we need to check the database to see if that person already exists, if not, decide to create a new person record

Comment: Is there any restriction on how form can be formed? Can there be more than one user with the same first name/last name, street address ect? Or are you saying only when all of the fields are identical down to every character will it not be created.

Comment: A person could have identical addresses or last names, like a spouse. We did not create the form, we are consuming the data collected by the form then performing a search